# How to connect number and names?

Tags: java

So the program should ask for the names and finishing times of three runners and  print the times and names in numeric order. Right now it does just print the numbers. How do i connect them? Since i cant connect Strings and ints? And when i tried make one or the other to either a String and an int it dosent work in the if sections.

```java
import java.util.scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        String name1;
        String name2;
        String name3;
        char repeat = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the first runner:");
            name1 = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the finishing time:");
            a = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the name of a second runner:");
            name2 = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the finishing time:");
            b = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the name of a third runner");
            name3 = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the finishing time");
            c = keyboard.nextInt();

            //The problem should be solved here?

            int min;
            int max;
            int med;

            if (a > b) {
                if (a > c) {
                    max = a;
                    if (b > c) {
                        med = b;
                        min = c;
                    } else {
                        med = c;
                        min = b;
                    }
                } else {
                    med = a;
                    max = c;
                    min = b;
                }
            } else {
                if (b > c) {
                    max = b;
                    if (a > c) {
                        med = a;
                        min = c;
                    } else {
                        med = c;
                        min = a;
                    }
                } else {
                    med = b;
                    max = c;
                    min = a;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(min);
            System.out.println(med);
            System.out.println(max);
        } while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `String` type variables for storing names corresponding to `min`, `med` and `max` as follows:

```
do {
    //...
    String medName = "";
    String minName = "";
    String maxName = "";    
    if (a > b) {
        if (a > c) {
            max = a;
            if (b > c) {
                med = b;
                min = c;
                medName = name2;
                minName = name3;
            } else {
                med = c;
                min = b;
                medName = name3;
                minName = name2;
            }
            //...
        }        
    }
    System.out.println("Name :"+ minName+", Finishing time: "+ min);
    System.out.println("Name :"+ medName+", Finishing time: "+ med);
    System.out.println("Name :"+ maxName+", Finishing time: "+ max);
} while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
```

**Finished code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        String name1;
        String name2;
        String name3;
        char repeat = 0;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the first runner: ");
            name1 = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the finishing time: ");
            a = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the name of a second runner: ");
            name2 = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the finishing time: ");
            b = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the name of a third runner: ");
            name3 = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the finishing time: ");
            c = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();

            int min;
            int max;
            int med;
            String medName = "";
            String minName = "";
            String maxName = "";

            if (a > b) {
                if (a > c) {
                    max = a;
                    if (b > c) {
                        med = b;
                        min = c;
                        medName = name2;
                        minName = name3;
                    } else {
                        med = c;
                        min = b;
                        medName = name3;
                        minName = name2;
                    }
                } else {
                    med = a;
                    max = c;
                    min = b;
                    medName = name1;
                    maxName = name3;
                    minName = name2;
                }
            } else {
                if (b > c) {
                    max = b;
                    if (a > c) {
                        med = a;
                        min = c;
                        medName = name1;
                        minName = name3;
                    } else {
                        med = c;
                        min = a;
                        medName = name3;
                        minName = name1;
                    }
                } else {
                    med = b;
                    max = c;
                    min = a;
                    medName = name2;
                    maxName = name3;
                    minName = name1;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Name :" + minName + ", Finishing time: " + min);
            System.out.println("Name :" + medName + ", Finishing time: " + med);
            System.out.println("Name :" + maxName + ", Finishing time: " + max);

            System.out.print("Do you want to repeat[Y/N]: ");
            String choice = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (choice.length() > 0) {
                repeat = choice.charAt(0);
            }
        } while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, when I use this it shows me a problem that the minName, medName and maxName have not been initialized

Comment: @HugoNilsson - Now, I've initialized them with `""`. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue.

Comment: Im very sorry to keep asking but Im very new to this. I cant seem to figure out how to initialize the min, max and med since I get that they cant be resolved to a variable even when i have int before all of them

Comment: @HugoNilsson - You must have done some typo. I've posted the finished code as well now. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach is to have a Player class with two fields,

```
    class Player implements Comparator
    {
      String name;
      int timeTaken;
      //add getter and setter
      // most importantly override Equal, hashcode and compare
    

      @Override
      public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        //compare them with timeTaken
      }
    }
```

Now in your main program, once you get the input, you should create player objects and store it inside a `TreeSet`

Just print your tree set, it will be in sorted order based on timeTaken.